# Splitting polygon on the curving edges using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting, polygon-creation

I have a set of polygons with irregular shapes, I am interested in cutting these polygons in the curves:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

How could I solve it?

I tried to use the vertices of the curves without much success.

A sample of data can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bX5WR7bg8-yVKmGujgtrcp3eS5tTBMie/view

Comment: @Taras Yes! here I leave you a sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bX5WR7bg8-yVKmGujgtrcp3eS5tTBMie/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You had a tag for PyQGIS but have not included a code attempt and so I have removed it.

Answer (score 4):

Working with provided input layer called *'data'*, see the image below.

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Apply the ["Oriented minimum bounding box"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#oriented-minimum-bounding-box) geoalgorithm

[image: step1]

**Step 2.** Make use of the ["Centroids"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#id302) and the ["Extract vertices"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices) tools. The ["Delete duplicate geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicate-geometries) can be also useful for vertices

[image: step2]

**Step 3.** Proceed with the ["Join by lines (hub lines)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#join-by-lines-hub-lines) between each centroid and a set of vertices.

[image: step3]

**Step 4.** ["Aggregate"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate) the output from the previous step. Where each part connects with its logical elongation

[image: step4]

**Step 5.** Apply the ["Split with lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) and get the final result

[image: step5]